# How come a new instance is created without the new operator?

Tags: javascript

With this code ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Izhaki/nyqqh4n5/)):

```
Animal = function() {
};

Animal.prototype.bark = function() {};

Animal.inspect = function() {
    console.log( this.prototype.hasOwnProperty( 'bark' ) ); // true
}

Animal.inspect();
```

`this` within `inspect` seems to be a new instance of Animal (rather than the global or `window` scope).

How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an instance of `Animal`, but the `Animal` object itself (`Animal`  is actually not a class)

The `this` variable is not an equivalent of the object instance (like `self` in many other languages). It is a "context" that may hold any value. This value can be resolved in many (confusing) ways. One of them is within a function call, where the function is a member of an object (and the function was not called specifying a new context via `.call` or `.apply`), in which case it will resolve to the object instance. Since `Animal` is an object, `Animal.inspect` qualifies as "method" and in `Animal.inspect()` the context  `this` is resolved to `Animal`.

You can do this small experiment:

```
Animal = function() {
};

Animal.prototype.bark = function() {};

Animal.doSomething = function() {
    this.hello = 'hello';
};

Animal.doSomething();
console.log(Animal.hello); // hello
```

And by the way, in JS you can perfectly create new objects without the `new` operator, as actually you did while defining `Animal`.

Comment: JS doesn't have classes as such, but Animal is a "class" in as much as it is possible to write `new Animal()` and get an instance of something that has a `bark` property (but it won't have an `inspect` property)

Comment: @ChrisLear I agree, and I don't. `new Animal` is not an instance of `Animal`, it is an object that delegates on `Animal`. Anyway... let's not discuss in depth the weirdnesses of JS :)

Comment: @bgusach: Of course `new Animal instanceof Animal`?! The object (we call it an instance) does delegate to `Animal.prototype`.

Comment: @Bergi, yeah you are right. Javascript is broken at so many levels, that you can't define anything consistently. JS claimed not to have classes but it provided `new` and `instanceof`. `Animal` is a function (and therefore an object), and you can "instantiate" a function. Absurd.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't creating an instance.

You call `inspect()` on the constructor object itself.

So `this` is `Animal` and then you examine the **prototype** (not the current object) to see if it has the back property.

Answer (score 2):

> `this` within inspect seems to be a new instance of `Animal`

first of all functions in JavaScript are also objects

so when you do the following

```
Animal.inspect();
```

`this` in `inspect()` is set to  `Animal`

Comment: Well, not necessarily.

Comment: "this in invoke()" what "invoke()"?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss sorry mistyped the method name

Comment: @bgusach i meant in the context of this call `Animal.inspect();`

Comment: @Ramanlfc, in that case you are completely right. But it is so easy to get confused and think that inside of that function `this` is meant to be the object owner...